# Generating Attachment Match Table in Enterprise Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, attachments

I've created a file geodatabase, imported a dataset, enabled attachments, generated an attachment match table and then added attachments. Everything worked perfectly and quickly.

When I tried the exact same thing in my enterprise geodatabase, ArcGIS 10.1 just takes forever and I can't seem to create the match table.

Is there anyway to copy the dataset with all the attachments from the file geodatabase to the enterprise geodatabase?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I figured out how to migrate a feature class from a file geodatabase to an enterprise geodatabase. I simply had to copy the feature class from the file geodatabase and paste it enterprise geodatabase, and all the attachments will be carried across. (I was previously importing the data from the file to the enterprise geodatabase.)

Still not sure why the generate attachment match table takes so long to create in my enterprise geodatabase ...